# Disable TableView Vertical Bounces When Scrolling with Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've been looking all over for the answer to this to no avail. When scrolling a TableView in a Titanium iPhone app, the TableView bounces when you've scrolled past it's top or bottom. It's supposed to be some kind of built in "Pull to refresh" functionality. How do I shut this off? Here is the answer for iPhone: [Disable UITableView vertical bounces when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768673/disable-uitableview-vertical-bounces-when-scrolling/17724196#comment30897019_17724196)

I don't know how to get this to work in a Titanium app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would rethink your desire to do this. It is not part of the pull-to-refresh, but is that natural table view behavior that iOS users have learned to expect over the past 6 years. Disabling it will feel very unnatural to your users and will stand out as a UI imperfection in your app.

If you have access to the table view object and can write arbitrary code (sorry, I am unfamiliar with how Titanium works), the API for this is to set `tableView.bounces = NO;`

Comment: Thanks. I'll relay the concern.

Comment: Here's the object's documentation in Titanium: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow

You'll see in the properties that there is no "bounces" property. Some other objects have a "disableBounce" property, but TableView does not :(

Also, `NO` would not be logical in JavaScript. It could be a boolean `false` or it could be the string `'no'` or `'NO'` or some constant like `Ti.UI.iOS.NO`

In fact, I might just try those options for fun. JavaScript is cool like that.

Comment: The syntax I wrote was objective-c, also those links you have are for the tableviewrow, not the tableview. But don't get your hopes up, the tableview doesnt have anything (documented) either