# Make the last row's bottom be the tableview's bottom (if enough rows)

Tags: swift, tableview, row, cell

Is there any way to avoid the tableview keep scrolling when reaching the bottom cell?

So far I managed to do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == dataArray.count - 1 {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

and that allows me only to stop the scroll when the user "rolled" the table to bottom. But after that the user can scroll again. Only if I could disable the "down" scrolling I could achieve it. Enabling it again as soon as it moved.

But it seems a lot of work just to do that, maybe I'm missing some property that fixes the last cell bottom to tableview's bottom.

Any ideas?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768673/disable-uitableview-vertical-bounces-when-scrolling

Comment: Have you tried disabling bounce on scroll to false.?

Comment: I'm trying to disable bounce as all the answers seem to advice this, but even if I set the footer view = Uiview() it creates me a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you need to do.

```
tableView.footerView = UIView()
tableView.bounces = false
```

And after the tableView has been reloaded.
`tableViewHeight`(your constraint)`.constant = tableView.contentSize.height`

This will cause the tableView to only display the populated cells, you will restrict the height to be as high as the content and you can't bounce the content as you want it to stop at last cell.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that an `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`

Starting here, you have 2 options :

1 - Disable the `bounces` effect : [tableView.bounces = false](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces)

2 - Prevent scroll further than the bottom of your tableView :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y =  scrollView.contentSize.height -  scrollView.bounds.size.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of them create still the empty space at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by disabling it directly from Storyboard:

[image]

**Disable the Bounce on scroll to Untick**

Also if u want to disable the lines coming at bottom when data is less you can use:

```
tableView.footerView = UIView()
```

Comment: Tried this and I still have a blank space at the bottom.

Comment: i did not get. i mean you are facing problem in scrolling or having issue in seeing lines at bottom.?

Comment: I guess it's both . I needed the table to stop scrolling so the last cells bottom == table bottom. Obviously i have to lost bounce for that. The problem now it's i keep seeing the empty space (and also a new empty space on heather)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us how you implemented Table view. So that i can look into that